# stx special character (0x02) breaking xml parse

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse an xml, either with `XElement.Parse` or with `XmlDocument.LoadXml` but seems like sometimes, the xml string has at its end and STX (0x02) special character and this is causing the parsing to fail.

Any hints?

Comment: I thought it might be a special case that can be treated somehow (instead of just replacing it with empty) :|

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is at the end, you can use [String.TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx).
If it is somewhere in the content (text or attribute) than replace it with its escaped value "&#0002"; or simply remove it.

Comment: The escaped form will only be accepted if you use an XML 1.1 parser.